# Why won't this C program let me access memory?

Tags: c, debugging, struct, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to do a linked list database and for some reason the program won't let me access the memory, or at least that's what the debugger says. I'm using the gdb debugger, codeblocks.

I've already compiled the program on another machine, with the same operating system (windows). It worked flawlessly, BUT the debugger showed the same error.

```
void print_ListEl(ListEl* head)
{
 ListEl* current = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
 current = head;
 if (head==NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 if (current->next==NULL)
 {
     puts("No elements");
     return;
 }
 else
 {
     int i=1;
     while(current->next!=NULL)
     {
         printf("%d.%s\n", i, current->name);
         current=current->next;
         ++i;
     }
 }
 free(current);
}
```

It's used like that:

```
ListEl* element = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
print_listEl(element);
```

This is the function that seems to cause the problem according to the debugger. When I watch the "current->next" variable, the debugger says "Cannot access memory at address". If I change current->next to current, the debugger still shows the same function as causing the problem. The ListEl structure is just a regular single linked list with a char type data.

```
 struct ListEl
 {
     char name[MAX_CHAR];
     struct ListEl* next;
 };
```

I also use

```
typedef struct ListEl ListEl
```

Headers are safe with *ifndef* and *endif* and are all included, I've checked.

This function, instead of putting "No elements" when there's no elements in the list, spews out some random character and crashes the program.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. This code doesn’t show cleary what is `head`, you talk about passing arguments to a function but there’s no function here etc. We need a complete code to know what’s happening.

Comment: You should update the code to show what the function parameters are.  Clearly you are using `malloc` and `free` but then comment elsewhere that you didn't mean to use it in that function.  Is `head` passed into the function.  Also `malloc` doesn't clear the data it points to.  In this case `element` still needs to be initialized so that `name` and `next` have meaningful values.

Comment: @user10605163 thank you, however after changing the code so that I don't use malloc or free, the function still seems to cause a problem in the debugger (and crashes the program) EVEN if I allocate memory to member "next" of the list element passed to the function.

Comment: @Mihu Yes the reason is missing initialization as pointed out by bruno. I have added my comment together with the initialization problem as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not supposed to `malloc` for `current`. You are replacing the pointer obtained from it immediately with `head` and loose the allocation. The later `free` will free the last element of the list, but will not set the pointer of the previous element to `NULL`, causing undefined behavior if the list is used later.
2. You are allocating memory for a node here:

   ```
   ListEl* element = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
   ```

   but you never set any of its values before calling `print_listEl(element);`. Therefore the pointer `element->next` will be indeterminate and comparison against `NULL` will not be useful. You dereference this pointer later in `print_listEl` causing undefined behavior. Always initialize after `malloc`:

   ```
   ListEl* element = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
   element->next = NULL;
   memset(element->name, '\0', sizeof(element->name));
   ```

Answer (score 2):

may be

```
ListEl* current = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
current = head;
```

must be

```
ListEl* current = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
head = current;
```

else why to do the malloc and lost it immediately ?

---

I hope you have additional code before

```
if (current->next==NULL)
```

because current is only allocated, not initialized

---

*When I watch the "current->next" variable, the debugger says "Cannot access memory at address".*

That means *current* was broken because for instance it was deleted, or you just never initialized the field *next*. the problem is you do not give [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

If you code is really that :

```
ListEl* element = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));
print_listEl(element);
```

*element->name* nor *element->next* are not initialized, so in `print_listEl` it is the same

Comment: Well, that doesn't really solve my problem. I want current=head, not head=current so I should've just skipped using malloc.

Comment: @Mihu I edited my answer, the problem is you do not give us enough source code, we don't see how you initialize your cells

Comment: True, the source is incomplete.  @Mihu you need to use `malloc` or an equivalent to allocate dynamic memory, so you can't "just skipped using malloc" or you have no way to initialize an arbitrary amount of elements for your list.  Reread this answer and try to understand it before you say it doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: I've added an edit which might make the code more understandable. What I get from your answer, I cannot check if member "next" of a list is equal to NULL if I don't alloc "element.next"? How would I check if a list is empty then?

Comment: By "skipping malloc" I mean that it's unnecesary here, as I've allocated memory for "head" previously, so I guess i don't need to allocate it to "current" just to overwrite it with "head" in the next line.

Comment: @Mihu when you create a new cell you need *always* to set its fields *including next* else their value is undefined. While you will not give more from your code it is not possible to progress, do you think we have a magic crystal ball to guess what you did ?

Comment: @bruno I've shown you how I declare a variable and pass the variable as an argument to the function, and I showed you the whole function. What else can I show that is relevant to this question?

Comment: @Mihu do you understand the meaning of the word _initialize_ ? `ListEl* element = malloc(sizeof(ListEl));` *only* allocate a piece of memory and save its address into _element_, but the allocated memory is *not initialized* this means the fields name and next have a unknown value